# Trouble with Ubuntu 18.04 netplan bridge on VirtualBox

Tags: networking, 18.04, server, netplan

I'm stuck in here in the network configuration and I need help..

Plan is to create a KVM with windows running on a dedicatet ubuntu 18.04 server.

So I need a networkbridge to reach the windows in my ubuntu. To try out this bridge-project I have create a ubuntu 18.04 server in my virtualbox and try to setup a running network-bridge there..

Everytime I apply my netplan config, the network connection stop working..

I really need help there and an explanation how this magic stuff work.. Of course I have googled but I havent found an explanaition or an example that work or helped me to understand.

Here is the working /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml - config from my ubuntu vm.

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
    gateway4: 192.168.176.1
    dhcp4: false
    addresses: [192.168.176.40/23]
  version: 2
```

Now I have tried to configure a bridge:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: false
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [192.168.176.40/23]
      gateway4: 192.168.176.1
      interfaces:
        - enp0s3
```

If I ran an 'netplan apply' now, the ssh-connection to my VM break up and the connection to the internet is also dead..

Can you help me with that problem and explain me what I have to do here.. ?

Here I have an 'ifconfig' from the runnung config for you:

```
root@vmbuntuerver18:/etc/netplan# ifconfig
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.176.40  netmask 255.255.254.0  broadcast 192.168.177.255
        inet6 2003:d3:cf20:ce00:a00:27ff:fee9:ad0d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fee9:ad0d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:e9:ad:0d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 787  bytes 71995 (71.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 546  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 122  bytes 18977 (18.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 92  bytes 7036 (7.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 92  bytes 7036 (7.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

And here an 'ifconfig' with my broken bridge-config:

[image]

(i cant copy the text, therefore here a picture)

I'am grateful for every idea or answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could resolve my problem by enableing the promiscuous-mode in the VM-setting from my VertualBox.

My 'bridged-config' is working.

Here a Picture from my VirtualBox network-setting:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to also apply indentation after the br0 line for the bridge, as follows:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: false
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [192.168.176.40/23]
      gateway4: 192.168.176.1
      interfaces:
        - enp0s3
```

Comment: thx for reply, i already have the blanks there, i have copied it wrong... sry -> i edit my question

Comment: the 'netplan generate' and 'netplan apply' runs successfully

Comment: The only thing you are missing under your `br0:` compared to my netplan config (which also has a bridge) is a `nameservers:` entry, also wift an `addresses:` line.

Comment: aaah i have found the issue.... I have to enable the promisquous mode in the virtual box setting -> if i turn on this option, the connection to and from my vm work ... -> my given config is working

Comment: thank you for your time and ideas!

Comment: Good to hear that!

Comment: do you have an idea, how i can port this solution to my dedicated server? If i use this config there, the network connection get broken -> see my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63339956/trouble-with-ubuntu-18-04-netplan-bridge-on-hetzner-server